# How to enforce uniqueness constraint on a whole column in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: database, orm, sqlalchemy, unique, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy class. I'm using the MySQL backend.

```
class MyClassA(db.Model):
    b = db.Column(db.String(12))
    c = db.Column(db.String(12))
```

I want to make sure that the values of `b` are unique over the whole column. How can I change this declaration to enforce that constraint?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the flag `unique=True` as specified in SQLAlchemy's [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.unique):

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), **unique=True**)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True)
```

I hope this helps